# Is Engi Med-Bot Dispersal affected by MedBay upgrades?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The title pretty much says it all. Do med-bay upgrades make healing in rooms besides the med-bay faster when you have med-bot dispersal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a **developer** who has answered that med-bay upgrades do **not** affect the Engi med-bot dispersal healing speed: [source](http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1448&p=5188&hilit=dispersal#p5475).

I also measured the effect with a fully upgraded and fully powered med-bay. Before any upgrades, it took 10 seconds for a crew member to hit 50% health in front of an open airlock. After all upgrades and med-bay fully powered, it took 10 seconds for a crew member to hit 50% health in front of an open airlock.

**Engi Med-Bot Dispersal is not affected by MedBay upgrades.**

Comment: Welp, can't argue with the code. Guess I'll switch accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i've currently got that same setup in my save-game. It does increase the rate although it still seems to be reduced as compared to manning the med-bay.

Comment: +1: This agrees with both my experiences, and my reading of the description. Reduced healing outside the medbay makes sense to me as a proportion of the healing *inside* the me bay.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with an Enig and an airlock. With no med bay 50% health took 7.6 seconds, with 1 med bay it took 10.5s, and with 2 med bay it took 10.5s. So as of 2023 extra power to med bay either has no impact, or has a negligible impact.