# Can Engi Med-bot Dispersal and Emergency Respirators together cancel health loss in vacuum?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've played with the Kruos and got the Med-bot augmentation.

My ship got destroyed before getting a med-bay. Now I wonder if both augmentations together can cancel the health loss that most races suffer in vacuum.

An entirely oxygenless ship would be a good defence against boarders. Having the advantages of non-lanius races in addition to that seems to be a desirable setup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a little math we can figure out the answer:

[From here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84552/is-engi-med-bot-dispersal-affected-by-medbay-upgrades) we know that with the medi-bot active, it takes 10 seconds to do 50% damage to a crew member, so the crew takes 5 HP/S.

Normally, it would take [15 seconds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85354/how-quickly-do-crew-suffocate-without-oxygen) for a crew member to die.  From that answer we also know that vacuum does 6.67 HP/s damage.

So medi-bot basically heals for 1.67 HP/S.

Emergency Respirators reduces vacuum damage to 50% (3.33 HP/S).

So no, the medi-bot alone won't be enough for your crew to survive in a vacuum.  However, crystal crew members, who already take less damage from vacuums, will be able to survive indefinitely.

Comment: After first reading your answer I still had hope to pull this off by upgrading the med-by, but following the first link shattered this hope with the destructive force of a rockman's fist. =(

Comment: And, of course, best of luck getting a Crystal crew-member.